# EXCEPTION: Token must be defined

Tags: node.js, angular

Unable to resolve this, I am not sure why its coming.

boot.ts

```
    "use strict";
import {bootstrap} from '../angular2/platform/browser';
import {appComponent} from '../components/app/appComponent';
bootstrap(appComponent);
```

appComponent.ts

```
    'use strict'
import {Component} from '../../angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'components/app/app.html'
})
export class appComponent {
    message:string='Hello html'; 
}
```

and in HTML file

```
<script>
         System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {        
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }  
        }

      });
        System.import('components/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

and stack trace
[image]

Comment: Looks like `appComponent` in boot.ts is undefined and it "must be defined". Not enough information here to figure out why...

Comment: Please create a Plunker that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Have you find a solution ?

Comment: What is your configuration ? (which beta of angular ? which version of rxjs ?)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you use relative path for angular2 modules. Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
'use strict'; // <------------
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {appComponent} from '../components/app/appComponent';
bootstrap(appComponent);
```

and

```
'use strict';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // <------------
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'components/app/app.html'
})
export class appComponent {
  message:string='Hello html'; 
}
```

You need to include Angular2 dist like this into your HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
(...)
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry