# appComponent is undefined in boot.ts

Tags: angular

I included appcomponent in bootstrap.ts but still appComponent in undefined, which leads to an error "Token must be defined"

here is my appComponent.ts file

```
'use strict'
import {Component} from '../../angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'components/app/app.html'
})


export class appComponent {
    message:string='Hello html'; 
}
```

and boot.ts file

```
"use strict";
import {bootstrap} from '../angular2/platform/browser';
import {appComponent} from './app/appComponent';
console.log('appComponent',appComponent)//appComponent is undefined here
bootstrap(appComponent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXCEPTION: Token must be defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007498/exception-token-must-be-defined)

Comment: I think it's better to refine your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007498/exception-token-must-be-defined instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I'd suggest to check template syntax. Evey thing else seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Angular2 bundles through an NPM dependency, you need to include a set of JavaScript files. This way Angular2 registers its entry point modules against the prefix `angular2/` when adding corresponding JS files with `script` tags. For this reason, you should use modules like `angular2/core`, `angular2/common`, ... What you define in the import isn't actually a path but the name of a registered module.

The resolution by path (with relative path) is to use for the code of the application itself and eventually third-party libraries (if you use their sources in TypeScript for example).

The following configuration of SystemJS shows that for the `app` sub folder, SystemJS will look for modules to import by path:

```
System.config({
  packages: {        
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
```

For example, if you import the path `./app/app.component`, SystemJS will try to dynamically load the `./app/app.component.js` file that was transpiled from the `./app/app.component.ts` file .

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative imports for angular 2 as they will not match when running in the browser.

Instead use `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` and use the compiler option `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

With regards to the the undefined error. This means that your relative path is incorrect, **or** and most likely... Your module loader is not correctly determining the path for the module. To check this make sure that the Network tab in the Developer Tools shows the correct file coming from the correct location and that it has the correct extension (eg: `.js`)